# play and pause javascript functions for html5 video behaving unreliably

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding why this works in some cases but not in others.

My goal is to display the video, play it for 5 seconds, pause for 5 seconds, then continue playing.

I have put an alert so I can see if the pause function exists, which it does in every case I have tried (alert appears with "function", if it didn't exist it would say "undefined")

**HTML**

```
  <video id="previewvid" width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" poster="http://anotherwebsite/image">
     <source src="http://anotherwebsite/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     Video unavailable
  </video>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert (typeof document.getElementById('previewvid').pause)
    document.getElementById('previewvid').play()
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('previewvid').pause()
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('previewvid').play()
        }, 5000)
    }, 5000)
})
```

Experience:
On my desktop machine this works perfectly in Chrome, but on Firefox I get a MIME type error, I am not too fussed by that as this will be used 99.9% on mobile anyway.

On mobile devices, I have an HTC One M7 with all software up to date. The video can be played in both Chrome and the built in browser, but does not autoplay. I have the same result on iPhone 6.
I tried on an old Samsung (not sure what model, but several years old) and found the same problem in Chrome, but on the built in browser the autoplay worked perfectly as required.

I've googled this problem extensively and there doesn't seem to be any obvious reason why the play/pause functions are not reliable.

Is there any other way I can get around this issue? Or any explanation as to why these functions are so unreliable? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

**edit:** I should add, the "anotherwebsite" is a CDN where I am paying for the availability of the videos, they have confirmed everything at their end is set up correctly

Comment: Autoplay is desactivate by apple: In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. and autoplay is disabled to prevent unsolicited cellular download. see https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Comment: for firefox, he accept no HTML5 video but you can see more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats